# Wrapper Stopped When Run Sumo Collector Docker container

Tags: docker, wrapper, docker-image, apm, sumologic

I follow instruction in docker hub [Sumo Collector image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumologic/collector).
I'm on run container step 3 using command: docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name="sumo-logic-collector" sumologic/collector:latest AccessID AccessKey.

After the container start, it always exited with the logs below:

```
Running SumoLogic Collector...

wrapper  | The version of the script (3.5.49.1) doesn't match the version of this Wrapper (3.5.49). This might cause some problems

wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console

]0;Sumo Logic Collectorwrapper  | Java Service Wrapper Standard Edition 64-bit 3.5.49

wrapper  |   Copyright (C) 1999-2022 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.

wrapper  |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com

wrapper  |   Licensed to Sumo Logic Inc. for Collector

wrapper  | 

wrapper  | Launching a JVM...

jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...

jvm 1    |    . .       . .       . .    .       . .

jvm 1    | .+'|=|`+. .+'| |`+. .+'|=|`+.=|`+. .+'|=|`+.

jvm 1    | |  | `+.| |  | |  | |  | `+ | `+ | |  | |  |

jvm 1    | |  | .    |  | |  | |  |  | |  | | |  | |  |

jvm 1    | `+.|=|`+. |  | |  | |  |  | |  | | |  | |  |

jvm 1    | .    |  | |  | |  | |  |  | |  | | |  | |  |

jvm 1    | |`+. |  | |  | |  | |  |  | |  | | |  | |  |

jvm 1    | `+.|=|.+' `+.|=|.+' `+.|  |.|  |+' `+.|=|.+'

jvm 1    | Sumo Logic Collector Version 19.461-1

jvm 1    | Sumo Logic Build Hash e948f52189e8

jvm 1    | current folder:/opt/SumoCollector

jvm 1    |   * See /opt/SumoCollector/./logs for more details.

jvm 1    | WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

jvm 1    | WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

jvm 1    | WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

jvm 1    | WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

jvm 1    | ERROR StatusConsoleListener Appender Console cannot be located. Route ignored

jvm 1    | ERROR StatusConsoleListener Appender Console cannot be located. Route ignored

jvm 1    | usage: <program>

jvm 1    |  -b,--blades <arg>                                  Deprecated. Equivalent

jvm 1    |                                                     to sources option

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -c,--clobber                                       If there is any

jvm 1    |                                                     existing collector

jvm 1    |                                                     with the same name,

jvm 1    |                                                     that collector will be

jvm 1    |                                                     deleted.

jvm 1    |  -category,--category <arg>                         Source category for

jvm 1    |                                                     Collector (optional).

jvm 1    |  -cim,--instructionMode                             Auto start command

jvm 1    |                                                     channel with service

jvm 1    |                                                     on startup.

jvm 1    |  -description,--description <arg>                   Description for

jvm 1    |                                                     Collector (optional).

jvm 1    |  -disableUpgrade,--disableUpgrade                   Collector rejects the

jvm 1    |                                                     upgrade requests.

jvm 1    |  -enableActionSource,--enableActionSource           Collector allows

jvm 1    |                                                     script action source

jvm 1    |  -enableScriptSource,--enableScriptSource           Collector allows

jvm 1    |                                                     script source

jvm 1    |  -fields,--fields <arg>                             Fields for Collector

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -fipsJce,--fipsJce                                 Collector will be use

jvm 1    |                                                     FIPS-compliant JCE

jvm 1    |                                                     Provider for

jvm 1    |                                                     communicating with

jvm 1    |                                                     Sumo.

jvm 1    |  -forwardingRules,--forwardingRules <arg>           A JSON file describing

jvm 1    |                                                     a set of destinations

jvm 1    |                                                     and destination

jvm 1    |                                                     forwarding rules.

jvm 1    |                                                     (Optional)

jvm 1    |  -h,--home <arg>                                    Collector home

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional)

jvm 1    |  -hostName,--hostName <arg>                         Host name for

jvm 1    |                                                     Collector (optional).

jvm 1    |  -i,--accessid <arg>                                Access id for

jvm 1    |                                                     registration

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -k,--accesskey <arg>                               Access key for

jvm 1    |                                                     registration

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -n,--name <arg>                                    Name to register

jvm 1    |                                                     collector as.

jvm 1    |  -proxyHost,--proxyHost <arg>                       Proxy host (optional).

jvm 1    |  -proxyNtlmDomain,--proxyNtlmDomain <arg>           NTLM user

jvm 1    |                                                     domain(optional).

jvm 1    |  -proxyPassword,--proxyPassword <arg>               Proxy user

jvm 1    |                                                     password(optional).

jvm 1    |  -proxyPort,--proxyPort <arg>                       Proxy port (optional).

jvm 1    |  -proxyUser,--proxyUser <arg>                       Proxy user (optional).

jvm 1    |  -r,--retry                                         Registration of

jvm 1    |                                                     collector will be

jvm 1    |                                                     retried if it fails on

jvm 1    |                                                     the first try.

jvm 1    |  -restForwardMetadata,--restForwardMetadata <arg>   Add metadata to data

jvm 1    |                                                     being forwarded to a

jvm 1    |                                                     rest sink (optional).

jvm 1    |  -s,--sources <arg>                                 A JSON file describing

jvm 1    |                                                     file sources to

jvm 1    |                                                     configure on

jvm 1    |                                                     registration

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -skipAccessKeyRemoval,--skipAccessKeyRemoval       Skip the removal of

jvm 1    |                                                     access key from

jvm 1    |                                                     user.properties

jvm 1    |  -syncSources,--syncSources <arg>                   A JSON file describing

jvm 1    |                                                     file sources. Use this

jvm 1    |                                                     option instead of

jvm 1    |                                                     "sources" if you wish

jvm 1    |                                                     the Collector to

jvm 1    |                                                     continuously monitor

jvm 1    |                                                     this file and

jvm 1    |                                                     synchronize the

jvm 1    |                                                     collector

jvm 1    |                                                     configuration

jvm 1    |                                                     according to changes

jvm 1    |                                                     in this file.

jvm 1    |                                                     (Optional)

jvm 1    |  -t,--ephemeral                                     Collector will be

jvm 1    |                                                     deleted after goes

jvm 1    |                                                     offline for a certain

jvm 1    |                                                     period of time.

jvm 1    |  -targetCPU,--targetCPU <arg>                       CPU target expressed

jvm 1    |                                                     as a percentage

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -timeZone,--timeZone <arg>                         Time zone for

jvm 1    |                                                     Collector (optional).

jvm 1    |  -token,--token <arg>                               Security token for

jvm 1    |                                                     registration

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -u,--url <arg>                                     URL to Sumo Service

jvm 1    |                                                     (optional).

jvm 1    |  -z,--installerMode                                 When in installer

jvm 1    |                                                     mode, Collector will

jvm 1    |                                                     provide feedback about

jvm 1    |                                                     registration through

jvm 1    |                                                     an installer results

jvm 1    |                                                     file.

wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issues? Thank you in advance!

I already create access Id and Key and leave everything else by default ([sumo-sources.json](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-collector-docker/blob/master/docker-sources/sumo-sources.json).).
Do I miss any important configure?

Comment: Did you get to solve this? I am facing similar issue when trying to deploy this as a sidecar in AWS ECS